# Flash text gradient

Tags: flash, gradient

I am trying to set gradient for a text in flash. But it never works. It only shows solid color.

How it can be done?

Comment: how are you trying to do it? post the code

Answer (score 5):

You can just make an object with a gradient fill, then put your text on a new layer and set that layer as a mask for the gradient object. If you put your text inside a movieclip of its own it will even work with dynamic text

Comment: +1 For "put your text inside a movieclip", I was previously trying with dynamic text without a movieclip.